# Sorting 2 sets of different arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
int main(){
int arr[5] = {5,4,2,1,3 };
string arr1[5] = { "R","E","E","P","T"};
pair<int, string> pair[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    pair[i] = make_pair(arr[i], arr1[i]);

}
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

I have 2 arrays, an `int` array and `string` array. Now I want to sort these array. As you can see number 5 is associated to 'R', and number 4 is associated to 'E'. I want to pair them up and then sort them by the `int` values from smallest to largest, so the sorted version should be like

```
"1 2 3 4 5"
"P E T E R"
```

I looked up some methods and come up with `pair`, but not entirely sure how to use it. Am I using it wrong? And what should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to use a map:

```
std::map<int, char> letters{{5, 'R'}, {4, 'E'}, {2, 'E'}, {1, 'P'}, {3, 'T'}};

for (auto& letter : letters)
    std::cout << letter.second;
```

It sorts based on the key (in this case an int) and by default sorts how you want.

Edit:
You could also use what you've already got, like this:

```
// sort array of pairs
std::sort(std::begin(pairs), std::end(pairs));

// print them out
for (auto& letterPair : pairs)
    std::cout << letterPair.second;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, But What if you are given 2 sets of array, and you need to sort them, in my way? is pair a good way to do it?

Comment: @Dave you probably don't need lambda. Also `right.first;` should be `r.first`, typo

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map as follows if you have C++11 compiler:

```
std::map<int, string> pair_map;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   pair_map.emplace_back(arr[i], arr1[i]);

}
```

In c++098

```
    std::map<int, string> pair_map;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       pair_map.insert(make_pair(arr[i], arr1[i]));    
    }
```